# How to calculate The duration/age in year, month, days between two dates in SQL? instituitiondate and nextdate has "date" data type?

Tags: sql-server, date

How to calculate The duration/age in year, month, days between two dates in SQL? instituitiondate and nextdate has "date" data type?

This is what I've tried:

```
SELECT
    instituitiondate, 
    MAX(NextDate) AS LastDate,
    DATEDIFF (YEAR, InstituitionDate, MAX(NextDate)) Years, 
    DATEDIFF (MONTH, InstituitionDate, MAX(NextDate)) Months, 
    DATEDIFF (DAY, InstituitionDate, MAX(NextDate)) Days 
FROM
    Main_Cause_List 
WHERE
    CaseNo = '372/4/2020' 
GROUP BY
    InstituitionDate;
```

Comment: i want to to calculate the age of the case on the basis of NextDate-InstituitionDate=TotalDuration @marc

Comment: What is the issue with your current query ? What is not working ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please move the body of your question from the title to the actual body and explain clearly what you're trying to achieve and/or what's not working with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there is an exact answer to your question, but this should give a very good approximation:

```
SELECT
    instituitiondate, 
    MAX(NextDate) AS LastDate,
    floor(datediff(day, InstituitionDate, MAX(NextDate)) / 365.25) as Years, 
    floor(datediff(day, InstituitionDate, MAX(NextDate)) / 30.4375) % 12 as Months, 
    floor(datediff(day, InstituitionDate, MAX(NextDate)) % 30.4375) as Days 
FROM
    Main_Cause_List 
WHERE
    CaseNo = '372/4/2020' 
GROUP BY
    InstituitionDate;
```

It calculates the age considering an average of 365.25 days per year, and 30.44 days per month.

**Edited**: changed the days per month from from 30.44 to 30.4375 because 30.4375 * 12 = 365.25, removing the very small inconsistency on the way the years are calculated versus their correspondent months and days left.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    instituitiondate, 
    MAX(NextDate) AS LastDate,
    floor(datediff(day, InstituitionDate, MAX(NextDate)) / 365.25) as Years, 
    floor(datediff(day, InstituitionDate, MAX(NextDate)) / 30.44) % 12 as Months, 
    floor(datediff(day, InstituitionDate, MAX(NextDate)) % 30.44) as Days 
FROM
    Main_Cause_List 
WHERE
    CaseNo = '372/4/2020' 
GROUP BY
    InstituitionDate;
```

Comment: (You missed correcting one alphabetic procession to *InstitutionDate*.)